# How to format a string with floats in Ruby using #{variable}?

Tags: ruby

I would like to format a string containing float variables including them with a fixed amount of decimals, and I would like to do it with this kind of formatting syntax:

```
amount = Math::PI
puts "Current amount: #{amount}"
```

and I would like to obtain `Current amount: 3.14`.

I know I can do it with

```
amount = Math::PI
puts "Current amount %.2f" % [amount]
```

but I am asking if it is possible to do it in the `#{}` way.

Comment: There are infinite ways to solve any programming problem, but some are a lot better than others. Why don't you want to use the right tool for this job?

Comment: Looking at the answers down below: None is a as clean as the % operator. I'll stick with that.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use [`round`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html#method-i-round):

```
"Current amount: #{amount.round(2)}"
```

Comment: Ah, ok. I tried the code in my IRB. It did not work. But the Ruby version of my system is 1.8.7.

Comment: Not sure about this - if you number is 11.3 and you want 11.30 you don't get the correct format...

Comment: Meanwhile, 11 becomes 11.0, which might not be what you want either.

Comment: I just discovered `amount.round(2).to_s.chomp('.0')`, which is ugly, but I think it works for my purposes.

Comment: This doesn't work for numbers like `5.684999905497534e-06 `. The `a.round(5)` will yield `1.0e-05`, whereas `'%.5f' % a` yields `"0.00001"`

Answer (score 79):

You can use `"#{'%.2f' % var}"`:

```
irb(main):048:0> num = 3.1415
=> 3.1415
irb(main):049:0> "Pi is: #{'%.2f' % num}"
=> "Pi is: 3.14"
```

Comment: Beware of different rounding:
```"%.2f" % 1.345
=> "1.34"```
```"%.2f" % 1.346
=> "1.35"```
```"%.2f" % 1.345.round(2)
=> "1.35"```
```"%.2f" % 1.346.round(2)
=> "1.35"```

Comment: Would be great to see a link to the documentation

Comment: The % operator documentation for the String class is here: https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.0/String.html#method-i-25

Answer (score 39):

You can do this, but I prefer the `String#%` version:

```
 puts "Current amount: #{format("%.2f", amount)}"
```

As @Bjoernsen pointed out, `round` is the most straightforward approach and it also works with standard Ruby (1.9), not only Rails:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-round

Comment: Why do you prefer the String version?

Comment: Because I try to reserve interpolation for simple expressions.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible:

```
puts "Current amount: #{sprintf('%.2f', amount)}"
```