# How to convert a float 0.0 into a return string of 0?

Tags: ruby

I'm running a program that returns `0.0` as a float. I need to convert it into a string that has no decimal places. How should I do this? Some examples of the inputs and the outcomes are as follows:

```
convert_number 0.0
# => "0"

convert_number 1.5
# => "1.5"

convert_number 2.0
# => "2"
```

How would I code method "convert_number"

Comment: What is your current code? What have you tried?

Comment: basically, I'm doing division and in order to not lose any precision, I'm dividing a number by 6.0.  The multiplication is working but then the problem is that if the result is an integer, I'm getting the first decimal place as a 0 but I would like it to automatically converted back to an integer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a string with floats in Ruby using #{variable}?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389567/how-to-format-a-string-with-floats-in-ruby-using-variable)

Comment: Thats not true because if for instance, the answer returns 1.5, then I don't want it converted into an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should suit your needs to convert floating integers to normal integers:

```
def convert_number(n)
  n == n.to_i ? n.to_i : n
end

convert_number(0.0)
=> 0
convert_number(1.5)
=> 1.5
```

If you need to make the additional conversion to a string, simply wrap the body of `convert_number` in parens and call `to_s`:

```
def convert_number_to_s(n)
  (n == n.to_i ? n.to_i : n).to_s
end

convert_number_to_s(1.5)
=> "1.5"
convert_number_to_s(2.0)
=> "2"
```

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily any need for any custom logic here, simply use [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) (via [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-25)):

```
'%g' % 1.0  #=> "1"
'%g' % 1.1  #=> "1.1"
```

But note that large numbers get converted to scientific notation:

```
'%g' % 1000000.0  #=> "1e+06"
```

See [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for more on `sprintf`’s formatting options.

Comment: +1.. New to me.. Not getting the difference between `%f` and `%g`... :(

Comment: Not a bad alternative solution, unless exponential notation does not suit the the needs of the OP in which case this only works for smaller numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def convert_number n
  (n == n.to_i) ? n.to_i.to_s : n.to_s
end
```

If you need to separate the truncation and conversion to string, the idiomatic way is as follows:

```
def convert_number n
  (n == n.to_i) ? n.to_i : n
end

> convert_number(3.0)
=> 3
> convert_number(3.0).to_s
=> "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you could use one of following methods:

```
 > 0.0.to_i.to_s
 => "0" 

 > 0.1.ceil.to_s
 => "1" 

 > 0.1.round.to_s
 => "0"
```