# How do I rounding of zeros in Ruby

Tags: ruby

When I round of 12121.232323 to 2 digit decimal point like below

```
p 12121.232323.round(2)
```

it is printing

```
12121.23
```

But when I try to round()

```
211211.00000.round(2)
```

it's printing

```
211211.0
```

But I want

```
211211.00
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a string with floats in Ruby using #{variable}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389567/how-to-format-a-string-with-floats-in-ruby-using-variable)

Comment: @iGian No ,it's not!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seek is not exactly rounding but formatting.

You can select your float formatting like this:

```
p "%.2f" % 12121.0000
```

where the `%.2f` part means "show 2 decimal points"

Answer (score 3):

```
'%.2f' % 12121.232323
```

or

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

number_with_precision(value, :precision => 2)
```